# How to improve search in Microsoft Document Explorer (dexplorer.exe)?

Tags: visual-studio

I use Microsoft Document Explorer version 9.0.21022.8.RTM. Why do I feel that using search in this MS Documentation is quite slow and quite bad? What i miss, what I do wrong?

**Quite slow**: When I search the same thing in google, yahoo or bing, i get the same results much faster. In dexplorer.exe i configured 20 results per page, local only. Each time i get 500 total results and of course I always find the thing I search in the first page of 20 results. In 'Tools' menu i can't configure to have total results first 50 or 100 max.

**Quite bad**: When i click F1 on a keywork in Visual Studio often i get very bad result in dexplorer. Some object which is quite far from what I do.

And in the end google becomes one of my best friends. I don't believe microsoft are stupid but they are flighting to prove it very hard. It's not a big problem but still i prefer to use a desktop app with much flexible & advanced search (like filtering language, platform, content, etc) then a browser.

Comment: Ha Ha! He wonders why a Microsoft product is slow and buggy!

Comment: The jokes are quite unneccessary and not helpful. I find most of Microsoft softwares quite good, and also fast and not buggy. There are other examples of buggy stuff, but the topic is not that. I'd like to share oppinions on dexplorer.exe, why didn't this tool offer upgrades and improvements over the years or can I improve experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your itty-bitty machine is no match against the hardware and smarts that Google throws at the search problem.  Use Google to search, you can use the site: selector to narrow the search to MSDN Library pages.  The Microsoft search page is not entirely unfunctional either but lately tends to show too many unhelpful MSDN forum questions.  You find topics in DE by using the index.  Which is very well done, it does take a bit of time to learn how to use it however.

The Contents tab is only useful when you found a topic and want to see associated topics or introductory material.  Use the "Sync with Table of Contents" button on the toolbar.  It doesn't always work for older topics.

Comment: I agree that desktop machine vs google hardware for search is no-match. But still my machine searches in a fixed content which is far away from 1 million positions, google searches on millions of unfixed content. Thanks for your very useful tips on using DE Index & "Sync with Table of Contents" button. I mostly used DE Search Tab and Contents Tab manually (treeview).